# Tmux: Map one default mapping to do nothing?

Tags: tmux

I map `C-b C-u` to `previous-window` and `C-b C-p` to `next-window` without problem.

BUT, the original `C-b C-n` is still doing `next-window`. My config:

```
unbind n
unbind C-n
```

the `C-b n` is disabled without problem, while `C-b C-n` seems impossible to be disabled.

In vim there is a command called `NOP`, which means "no operation". Does tmux have the equivalence?

---

If I did `tmux unbind-key C-n` in the Alacritty, it works:

[image]

If I did `unbind-key C-n` in the `~/.config/tmux/tmux.config`, it doesn't work:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your tmux version, but `tmux list-keys` should show you something like

```
bind-key -T prefix C-n  next-window
bind-key -T prefix n    next-window
```

where `-T prefix` shows it is using the "prefix" table (the one got to by `C-b`). So you can try adding to your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
unbind-key -T prefix C-n
unbind-key -T prefix n
```

Comment: I did. But then I typed `tmux list-keys` it still shows `bind-key    -T prefix       C-n                  next-window`... Why it's not unbind?

Comment: Sorry, there are 2 bindings, so you need 2 commands. See updated answer.

Comment: Still doens't work, I think this is caused by either Alacritty settings or the tmux-plugin(s) I use.

Answer (score 0):

If you:

- Has some keys **cannot** be `unbind` using `/.config/tmux/tmux.config` or `~/.tmux.config`.
- Directly typing `tmux unbind YOUR_KEY` in your terminal succeeded.

Then, add the following in your `.zshrc`/`.bashrc`:

```
[ -z "${TMUX}" ] || tmux unbind YOUR_KEY
```